# What is the probability that there are exactly 3 pennies in box number 1?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

One hundred pennies are being distributed independently and at random into 30 boxes, labeled 1, 2, ..., 30. What is the probability that there are exactly 3 pennies in box number 1?

I don't know what type distribution this problem involves and also how do I proceed to solve it? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Pick the three pennies that'll go in the first box in $\binom{100}{3}$ ways. Probability that three given pennies actually go into that box (and the other $97$ do not) is $(1/30)^3\cdot(29/30)^{97}$, so the answer is
$$\binom{100}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{30}\right)^3\cdot\left(\frac{29}{30}\right)^{97}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities relevant to the question: either a penny lands in box 1 (probability $\frac1{30}$) or it doesn't. Therefore a binomial distribution is in play and the answer is
$$\binom{30}3(1/30)^3(29/30)^{27}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here, $X \sim$ Binomial  $(100,\frac{1}{30})$ ; (Recall Binomial distribution with parameters (n,p))

Computing $P(X=3)$ would give you the answer.